# Mathematical induction with an inequality involving factorials

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, induction

How do I prove this inequality: $n!>2^n$, where $n\ge 4$. I've searched online but the solutions are vague to me. Thank you! :)

Comment: Please read your question carefully, I think there might be a typo.

Comment: @David thank you! edited :)

Comment: I changed the hypothesis $n>4$ to $n\ge 4$ since in the case $n=4$ the inequality is also true.

Comment: Instead of searching for solutions online, try to solve it yourself using induction, and explain here where you are stuck so we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proof by induction has three parts: a basis, induction hypothesis, and an inductive step. We show that the basis is true, and then assume that the induction hypothesis is true. We then use our assumption to imply this inequality is true for all other values.

Basis: Let $n=5$. Then $n!=5!=120$. $2^n=2^5=32$. $120>32$.

Induction hypothesis: Suppose $n=k>4$. Assume that $k!>n^k$ holds true.

Inductive: Now let $n=k+1$. $(n+1)!=(n+1)n!$. $2^{k+1}$= $2^k2$. We know $n!>2^k$, so now we must simply compare $n+1$ and $2$. $n$ is strictly greater than $4$, so $n+1$ is certainly greater than $2$. Thus $(n+1)!>2^{k+1}$.

Thus we have shown by induction that $n!>2^k$

Comment: does the same idea apply when 2^n instead of n^2?

Comment: Perhaps you mean n^2 instead of 2^n? The same idea for a proof by induction applies to anything you would like to prove by induction, but I can tell you right away that a factorial grows at a much faster rate than an n^2 polynomial and so the inequality will easily hold in that case.

Answer (score 1):

We will prove by induction

Base case $n=5$ , $5!=120>32=2^5$

Case $n=k$ assuming true for $n=k-1$

$(k-1)! >2^{(k-1)}$ multiplying by $k$ yields

$k(k-1)! >k*2^{(k-1)}> 2*2^{(k-1)}=2^k$ since $k>2$

$k! >2^k$

Answer (score 0):

Assume 
$$2^n<n!$$ multiply by $2$ to get 
$$2^{n+1}<2n!$$ and we see that 
$$2n!\leq(n+1)n!=(n+1)!$$